# xml flash gallery / joomla help needed

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, joomla1.5, gallery

I've bought the "virtual gallery" from flashden but I'm having problems implementing it.. I'm not used to using flash galleries or xml files, so hopefully someone can help me out a bit.

Here's the call to the flash (js):

```
  var so = new SWFObject("gallery.swf?xml=category_1.xml", "virtualgallery", "100%", "600", "10", "#414141");
  so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
  so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
  so.addParam("menu", "true");
  so.write("flashcontent");
```

Here's the xml options:

```
<options imagesFolder="images" thumbsFolder="images/thumbs" viewportMaxWidth="920" viewportMaxHeight="600" sfx="yes" />
```

And here's my structure and paths:

**Images**: /images/gallery/

**Thumbs**: /images/gallery/thumbs/

**XML**: /components/com_gallery/assets/

**SWF**: /components/com_gallery/assets/

And the component with the gallery (js) in it is /index.php?option=com_gallery&view=gallery&cid=7&Itemid=2 which is basically this:

/components/com_gallery/views/gallery/tmpl/default.php

I don't think the xml file likes using /images/gallery and I don't think the new SWFObject likes the paths to the swf file etc.. I hope I'm making sense here!

If anyone could help, that would be fantastic.. Thank you :)

Comment: Perhaps ask the guys you bought it from.

Comment: yeh I've asked them but they haven't responded yet, so I thought I'd check here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in the XML I had to do ../../images/gallery/ etc

Answer (score 1):

I apolagize if my answer is retardedly simple, but your xml option paths and your file structures don't match. This would make it so that the proper files can't be loaded.

Comment: lol yeh i know, i was showing what the default was, i tried changing it to the correct paths but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: does the xml values have to be the absolute path? eg.

/home/photogra/public_html/images/gallery/

or should /images/gallery/ work?

Comment: I assume you might have tried both those options. I don't believe it has to be an absolute path though.

Have you tried running the default flashden program as is on its own server?